# Unable to call External jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am unable to call the external jquery file. The code that is in the same aspx page is working but the external js is not working. Please help -

My aspx Page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="loginvalidation.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My external jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            <%=txtUserName.ClientID %>: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            <%=txtPassword.ClientID %>: {
                required: true,
                digits:true,
                minlength:10,
                maxlength:10
            }
        }, 
        messages: {
            <%=txtUserName.ClientID %>:{
                required: "* Required Field *"
            },
            <%=txtPassword.ClientID %>:{
                required:"* Required Field *"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Server Side code like `<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>` will not be work in JS file. They will not be parsed and will be rendered as simple text.

Comment: Then can you please tell me what should i use instead of this

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace `<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>` and `<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>` with generated client IDs when you move the script to external js file.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Server Side code like `<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>` will not be work in JS file. They will not be parsed and will be rendered as simple text.

You can use the [rules add function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

In ASPX Page, Add a CSS class (Here I have added *username*)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="username"></asp:TextBox>
```

In Your External File

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('form').validate(); 

    // Use custom class added to input and add rules like this
    jQuery('.username').rules('add', { 
        required: true, 
        email: true,
        messages: { 
            required: "* Required Field *" 
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the script complete path like

```
<script src="~/foldername/foldername/JScript1.js"></script>
```

you just need to pick the file and drop to the page in visual studio.

And also as comment suggested <%=txtUserName.ClientID %> these are asp.net code that would not work in javascript external file.

In place of it please follow any of the solution

**Solution 1**

Either use StaticId on controls or page by setting ClientIdMode = "Static". you can find more details on [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

like

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtUserName" runat="server" ClientIdMode ="static" />
```

After setting it you can aceess your controls like

```
$('#txtUserName')
```

**Solution 2**

Look into your html page that is rendered by Asp.net engine. Asp.net engine convert the controls id depends on Master page used and append it on the control id. Now rendered controlId should be look like 'ct100_txtUserName' and you can get your control like

```
$('#ct100_txtUserName')
```

**Solution 3**

Add classes on controls like

```
<asp:TextBox id="someId" CssClass="someClass" runat="server" />
```

and get the control like

```
$('.someClass')
```

But the last one is slow compare to other

Comment: can you please tell me what should i use instead of <%=txtUserName.ClientID %>  code?